# Is #include <../header.h> a bad practice in C++?

Tags: c++, directory, include-path

My c++ project in summary is composed of two directories and of course the `main.cpp`:

1. `Dataloader` containing **dataloader.h** and  **dataloader.cpp**
2. `Analysis` containing **analysis.h** and **analysis.cpp**

---

in **dataloader.h** I included **analysis.h** as follows:

```
#include<../Analysis/analysis.h>
```

---

My professor told me that it's a BIG NO NO!!!!!. We were trying to create a **makefile** and he was surprised. Why is it a bad practice? and how can I make the include simpler. I am working on `code::blocks` and gcc 4.8 compiler.

> N.B. I noticed that code::blocks some how forgives include errors. When
>   we tried to compiled it by using gcc command it went bad

---

Comment: What reason did he give you? Off-hand I don't see anything wrong with this.

Comment: If anything lose the `../` ... then it should probably be fine.

Comment: he said that it's a bad practice don't know why

Comment: As an instructor **he should tell you why — ask them**.

Comment: I would consider it hacky for <> but not "".

Comment: One more thing to consider is: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21594/499581

Comment: Usually a software under version control has a fixed file structure, or at least fixed relative path two or three directories above, so I think this is at least common practice among a lot of projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with your professor. Use of

```
#include<../Analysis/analysis.h>
```

makes the code brittle. If the code base is re-organized using a different directory structure, files containing such `#include` statements will fail to compile.

Regarding:

> N.B. I noticed that code::blocks some how forgives include errors. When we tried to compiled it by using gcc command it went bad

Add `-I.` to the compiler flags to resolve that problem.

Comment: actually it failed to compile when we were creating the makefile and compiling it with gcc command. Code::blocks is really forgiving makes work harder later. In the end it worked but wasn't satisfied with the include. thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Well I've always been taught, and this makes sense, that you should put your includes in the file that depends on them.

So in your situation, I assume you use `dataloader` to import data, and then the `analysis` to analyze it. Well in this case, it makes more sense to include both of these in the main.

In comparison, I made an n by n tic tac toe game that includes a `print_board()` function. This function relies on a header file with constants, `colors.h`, to properly print the board. So in this circumstance, it makes more sense for my `print_board.h` file to include the `colors.h` file, because it is directly dependent on it, and nothing else is.